# Jenkins Terraform Secret from Credential Manager with TF_VAR_

Tags: jenkins, terraform

Everything that I've been reading says that I should be using the TF_VAR_ method of passing my client secret to Terraform, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: No value for required variable

  on variables.tf line 1:
   1: variable "clientid" {

The root module input variable "clientid" is not set, and has no default
value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for
this variable.
```

Note that if I pass the values directly to apply with the -var flag, it works fine.  So, this question is about how to use the TF_VAR_ method, not how to az login.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
//Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker-agent' }

    environment {
        AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID='<......>'
        AZURE_TENANT_ID='<.......>'
        CONTAINER_REGISTRY='containerregistry'
        RESOURCE_GROUP='crrg'
        REPO="sftp01"
        IMAGE_NAME="sftptest"
        TAG="0.01"
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                //sh 'docker build -t containerregistry.azurecr.io/sftp01/sftptest:0.01 -f Dockerfile .'
                //sh 'echo built'
                
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'containerregistryCreds', passwordVariable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET', usernameVariable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID')]) {
                    
                    sh 'export TF_VAR_clientid=$AZURE_CLIENT_ID'
                    sh 'export TF_VAR_clientsecret=$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'
                    sh 'export TF_VAR_subscriptionid=$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'
                    sh 'export TF_VAR_tenantid=$AZURE_TENANT_ID'
                    
                    //sh 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
                    //sh 'az account set -s $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'
                    //sh 'az acr login --name $CONTAINER_REGISTRY --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP'
                    //sh 'az acr build --image $REPO/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG --registry $CONTAINER_REGISTRY --file Dockerfile . '
                    
                    sh 'terraform init'
                    sh 'terraform fmt'
                    sh 'terraform validate'
                    sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve -no-color'
                    
                    //If I pass the variables this way, it works fine.
                    //sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve -no-color -var clientid=$AZURE_CLIENT_ID -var clientsecret=$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -var subscriptionid=$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -var tenantid=$AZURE_TENANT_ID'
                    
                    sh 'terraform show'
                    sh 'terraform state list'
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  client_id       = var.clientid
  client_secret   = var.clientsecret
  subscription_id = var.subscriptionid
  tenant_id       = var.tenantid
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourceNameTFscopeOnly" {
  name     = "myTFResourceGroup"
  location = "westus2"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "clientid" {
  description = "Azure Client ID"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "clientsecret" {
  description = "Azure Client Service Principal Secret"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "subscriptionid" {
  description = "Azure Subscription ID"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "tenantid" {
  description = "Azure Tenant ID"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}

variable "testpassword" {
  description = "For testing (not relevant to question)"
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using curly brackets around the variable name for the client id, `${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}`? Also, you might want to remove subscription id if that is a sensitive value as well as any other sensitive value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `withCredentials` block in Jenkins Pipeline will already export your variables to the environment within its scope. You can additionally modify the `env` object for additional environment variables, and access current environment variables (such as those you are assigning in the `environment` directive) from the `env` object. This is the reason Terraform errors on no values for the variables: none of them are being set in the environment correctly.

```
// assign password and username environment variables within block arguments
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'containerregistryCreds', passwordVariable: 'TF_VAR_clientsecret', usernameVariable: 'TF_VAR_clientid')]) {
  script {
    // re-assign other environment variables from environment directive to env object within block scope           
    env.TF_VAR_subscriptionid = env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    env.TF_VAR_tenantid = env.AZURE_TENANT_ID
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax, as you wrote it, for this part:  env.TF_VAR_subscriptionid = env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID  doesn't seem to work.  Can you check that?   How exactly would you re-assign those values?  Thank you!

Comment: @AdamWinter My answer is correct given the question above. If something "does not seem to work" then you need to provide additional information, including at least an error message. Then I can update the answer for the new information.

Comment: WorkflowScript: 27: Expected a step @ line 27, column 21.
                       env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = env.TF_VAR_subscriptionid

Comment: Looks like scripts now have to be wrapped in a script block.  It works now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AdamWinter Yes if you had not executed any Groovy up to that point, then the Groovy needs to be inside a `script` block.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.  Thank you to Matt for answering the core question here.  Also, in order to keep the tenantId and subscriptionId out of source control, I put those in their own usernamePassword credential in Jenkins:

```
//Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker-agent' }
    environment {
        //TF_LOG='DEBUG'
        TF_LOG_PATH='/home/jenkins/terraform-debug.log'
        CONTAINER_REGISTRY='ArcticaCR'
        RESOURCE_GROUP='crrg'
        REPO="sftp01"
        IMAGE_NAME="sftptest"
        TAG="0.01"
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                
                withCredentials([
                    usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'sftpServicePrincipalCreds', passwordVariable: 'TF_VAR_clientsecret', usernameVariable: 'TF_VAR_clientid'),
                    usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'AzureTenantSubscription', passwordVariable: 'TF_VAR_tenantid', usernameVariable: 'TF_VAR_subscriptionid'),
                    usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'passwordtestCreds', passwordVariable: 'TEST_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'TEST_USERNAME')
                ]) {
                     
                    sh 'az login --service-principal -u $TF_VAR_clientid -p $TF_VAR_clientsecret -t $TF_VAR_tenantid'
                    sh 'az account set -s $TF_VAR_subscriptionid'
                    sh 'az acr login --name $CONTAINER_REGISTRY --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP'
                    sh 'az acr build --image $REPO/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG --registry $CONTAINER_REGISTRY --file Dockerfile . '
                    sh 'az logout'
                    
                    sh 'terraform init'
                    sh 'terraform fmt'
                    sh 'terraform validate'
                    
                    sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve -no-color -var testpassword=$TEST_PASSWORD'
     
                    sh 'terraform show'
                    sh 'terraform state list'

                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as already stated in the other answer, you export the variables in one `sh` step but you run the Terraform commands in another `sh` step. Exported values do not survive across steps as these steps are standalone Bash processes. But you can run it all in one step:

```
sh """
export TF_VAR_...=...
terraform ...
"""
```

I think solution with `env.TF_VAR_... = ...` is still nicer though.